# Что означает двоеточие в конструкторе

Tags: c++

```
class Exception
{
public:
    Exception(const wchar_t* szwText)
        :   m_wstrText(szwText)  // ВОТ В  ЭТОЙ СТРОКЕ
    {;}; 
    // дальнейшие определения

 }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Инициализация полей в конструкторе.
То есть, формально, понимайте это так

```
class Exception
{
public:
    Exception(const wchar_t* szwText)
    {
        m_wstrText = szwText
    }
//дальнейшие определения

 };
```

Только в первом случае компилятор может сделать код более эффективным.

в стандарте определено в пункте 12.6.2

Comment: <занудство>только в первом случае вызовется конструктор копирования, а во втором -- конструктор по умолчанию и оператор присваивания.</занудство>

Comment: но может и оптимизировать. и вызвать правильный конструктор сразу.

Comment: @KoVadim: угу, имеет право, даже если в разных конструкторах разные побочные эффекты

Comment: Но самое смешное, что будет требовать реализацию других конструкторов, которые по факту не использует, но стандарт требует:)

Comment: Угу, чтобы типа никто не знал, сработала оптимизация или нет :)

Comment: нет, потому что компилятор не знает, сможет ли он делать эту оптимизацию при следующей компиляции. Стандарт он хитрый, многие вещи описаны странно. Но чем глубже изучаешь язык, тем лучше понимаешь, что это именно так и нужно. Но, конечно, исключения есть.

Comment: На самом деле у второго способа есть преимущества. Я читал про это неоднократно. Вроде даже в самом Страуструпе. Тем более, что и такой код читабельнее, чем у ТС.

Comment: Какие такие преимущества?

Comment: @dzhioev, ну, например, в [FQA][1] говорят, что все плохо со списками инициализации...

[1]:http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.6

Comment: @gecube в Overload 112 интересная статья о том, как избежать "всего плохого"
@KoVadim ничего стандарт не требует, это эмпирическое "правило трех"

Answer (score 11):

К ответу [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) добавлю, что есть случаи, когда подобная конструкция не просто желательна, но и необходима

1. Вызов конструктора базового класса
2. Инициация константы
3. Инициация ссылки (не указателя!)

Возможно, что-то забыл. Если кто укажет другие случаи, буду благодарен.

**P.S.** Вот еще: включенный объект требует инициации конструктором с параметрами, а оператор присваивания у него отсутствует.

Comment: Инициализация включенного объекта, который не имеет конструктора без параметров, вроде, тоже невозможна без списка инициализации.

Comment: Да, совершенно верно.